# MUI DataGrid - Need to Add custom styling property to the data-grid

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

[**This is what I'm getting on building**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53XLO.png)

[**This is how I want the build to be**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM9aV.png)

I'm using a template and its has a predefined style class for dataGrid which is being applied to all the data-grid throughout the template.
I need to add a custom styled component for my data-grid in-order to achieve the design on the IMG-2.
Dependencies: @emotion/styled

The code for customize data grid:

> ```
>  const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)(({ theme }) => ({
>         root: {
>           '& .MuiDataGrid-renderingZone': {
>             maxHeight: 'none !important',
>     
>           },
>           '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
>             lineHeight: 'unset !important',
>             maxHeight: 'none !important',
>           },
>           '& .MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell ': {
>             maxHeight: 'none !important',
>             minHeight: 'mpne !important'
>           },
>           '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScrollerRenderZone .MuiDataGrid-row ' : {
>               maxHeight: 'none !important',
>     
>           }
>         },
>       }));
> ```

Data-Grid:

````
<StyledDataGrid
          rows={(temp.length === count ? rows : temp)}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={20}
          autoHeight
          rowHeight={465}
          getRowSpacing={getRowSpacing}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          getRowClassName={(params) => `super-app-theme--${params.row.qa_status} && ${params.row.pkg_status}`}
          components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        />
```
````

Answer (score 0):

add a property in your `<DataGrid>` name `sx :{}` just like this

```
<DataGrid
    columns={col}
    rows={Players}
    pageSize={10}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[8]}
    sx={{
   
      p: 4,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      font: 'center',
      borderColor: 'primary.light',
      '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:hover': {
        color: 'primary.main',
      },
    }}
    autoHeight
  />
```